# Outside ac unit drawing too many amps

Tags: electrical, hvac

I have an ac compressor, on my outside home ac unit, that is pulling 21 amps and the tag on compressor has a RL of 17.6.  Should I be worried?

Comment: Has the unit been serviced? Clean coils? Balanced freon (not too much nor too little)   all of those can make the unit work harder, thus drawing more amps. VAnother thing is it all original parts?  I've seen cases where it was an extremely energy efficient unit but someone came along and has to change the blower motor and put a cheap less efficient motor in its place instead of the spec'd OEM motor.

Comment: I will check all those out.  Thank you, Tyson

Answer (score 1):

How old is your condensing unit?  Your compressor may be getting close to it useful lifespan.  As internal wiring and parts become worn, the compressor will pull more amps over time until something eventually gives.  If it is still cooling and not tripping the breaker you should be ok.  But I would probably set a little cash back for that final day when the compressor fails.  Sometimes it is more feasible to replace the entire condensing unit in lieu of compressor replacement if the unit is an old one.

Comment: The unit is pretty old and is an R22 system.  I am planning on replacing it this winter.  I just didn't want it melting the contactor or catching fire.

Answer (score 1):

If the start run capacitor is failing this can cause a high current draw. R22 is being phased out and soon the cost of a recharge will be more than a replacement. With that said many times the caps or relays that control the unit need replacing. I have repaired several late 80's early 90's units lately that may run for another 5+ years with no add to the freon charge.

Comment: Thank you, Ed.  I will check the cap.  The unit itself (XR-11) is a 2003.  It is undersized for the size of my house.  That being said, It ran A LOT these past 2 summers here in Florida.  The unit is worn out.  Just trying to get to  winter were the prices will go down a bit on complete replacement.